# How to run two YOLOv5 models pose and non-pose consecutively?

Tags: python, yolov5

When i run each of the models separately they work perfectly fine, either pose or non-pose. As soon as i try to run them together they fail with shape error.

File "/home/user/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/yolo.py", line 61, in forward
x[i] = x[i].view(bs, self.na, self.no, ny, nx).permute(0, 1, 3, 4, 2).contiguous()
RuntimeError: shape '[1, 3, 57, 72, 120]' is invalid for input of size 155520

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by running it together?

Comment: To clarify i am trying to run two Yolov5 models on the GPU but it fails as it  seems to assign wrong weights or one weight to both model.